# Netty: when does writeAndFlush channel future listener callback get executed?

Tags: callback, netty

I am new to netty and trying to understand how the channel future for writeAndFlush works. Consider the following code running on a netty client:

```
final ChannelFuture writeFuture = abacaChannel.writeAndFlush("Test");
writeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        if (writeFuture.isSuccess()) {
            LOGGER.debug("Write successful");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Error writing message to Abaca host");
        }
    }
});
```

When does this writeFuture operationComplete callback executed?

1. After netty hands over the data to the OS send buffers (or)
2. After the OS writes the data to the network socket. (or)
3. After this data is actually received by the server.

TIA

Answer (score 5):

```
1. After netty hands over the data to the OS send buffers (or)
```

Listener will be notified after `data` is removed from `ChannelOutboundBuffer` (netty's send buffer)

Comment: @loxiu - so there is no notification if the data is received by the server? What if the receiver is blocked? How can I detect that?

Comment: Yes, no notification(or application level ack). If the receiver is blocked then sender's os buffer will full, then netty cant't send data and channel's writable will become false.

Comment: Tcp send from the sender is generally throttled(slowed down) if receiver is slow or blocked. Does this impact netty sends as well? Or does the channel simply become not writable after sending data as fast as possible?

Comment: I have added a SO question for some clarification perhaphs you could add answers there?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42750075/understanding-netty-channel-buffers-and-watermarks

Comment: @louxiu -- For every wirteAndFlush() operation we need to create and add a listener at runtime, is it too expensive? How to understand this?

Comment: @zipper I think a listener just for count is not expensive. Anyway you may need to profile it.