# Understanding netty channel buffers and watermarks

Tags: java, tcp, buffer, netty, channel

I am trying to understand netty buffers and watermarks.

As a test case, I have a netty server which writes to a client, the client is blocked (essentially has a sleep of 10 seconds between each read)

- Under normal I/O TCP sender would be throttled (sending is slowed down because of flow control) if the receiver is blocked, this is not the case here. The sender seems to keep writing and flushing data on each send. Where is this data being written? Is there going to be Flow control in the netty's flush() as well? 
  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control
- Is it is being written to an OS or TCP buffer, does netty channel have an internal buffer as well? If so how can I configure it?
- I track bytesBeforeUnwritable but they do not seem to be decreasing
- What is the default High and Low Watermark? I have not set anything in my application. Is there any way to use this instead?

Code below:

```
@Override
    public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {

        if (server2OutboundChannel.isActive()) {
            if(server2OutboundChannel.isWritable()) {
                server2OutboundChannel.writeAndFlush(msg).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                        if (future.isSuccess()) {
                            // was able to flush out data, start to read the next chunk
                            //System.out.println(server2OutboundChannel.bytesBeforeUnwritable());
                            ctx.channel().read();
                        } else {
                            future.channel().close();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }else{
                System.out.println("Channel is no longer writeable");
                System.out.println(server2OutboundChannel.bytesBeforeUnwritable());
                System.out.println(server2OutboundChannel.bytesBeforeWritable());
            }
        }
    }
```

Detailed steps to re-create with end-to-end source code:

- Clone https://github.com/nipunarora/nettyDuplicator .
- Specifically, the proxy code is here:

`https://github.com/nipunarora/nettyDuplicator/tree/master/src/main/java/org/columbia/parikshan/proxy`

- Compile and Build:

  `mvn package`
- Start the server

  `sh scripts/Server.sh 3380`
- Start the netty proxy

  `sh scripts/nettyProxy.sh -l 0.0.0.0:3379 -o 127.0.0.1:3380`
- Start the client

  `sh scripts/Client.sh 127.0.0.1 3379`
- send "hello" as std input in client
- netty blocks sending after some time and the bytesTillUnwritable do not decrease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is this data being written? Is there going to be Flow control in the netty's flush() as well?

The data went to `ChannelOutboundBuffer`. There is no Flow control like tcp. The data will be kept in `ChannelOutboundBuffer` until there is space in tcp's send buffer.

> Is it is being written to an OS or TCP buffer, does netty channel have an internal buffer as well? If so how can I configure it?

Netty has `ChannelOutboundBuffer` which keep data before send to OS'buffer. You can configure it like below.

```
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, soRcvBufSize);
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, soSndBufSize);
    bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, writeBufferHighWaterMark);
```

> I track bytesBeforeUnwritable but they do not seem to be decreasing

I write a [sample code](https://gist.github.com/louxiu/675027ae7563403dd8c71e4ae8ec095d) that server write to a blocked client

Your proxy's `AUTO_READ` is false. `NettyProxyFrontendHandler#channelRead` will only be called when `ctx.channel().read()` (in the future listener) is called. The listener will be called after `writeAndFlush` is completed. `writeAndFlush` will generate a task and the task will is done when the msg is write to OS's buffer. If OS's buffer is filled, the task will be blocked. There is no chance that netty's buffer will become unwritable, it is always writeable.

> What is the default High and Low Watermark? I have not set anything in my application. Is there any way to use this instead?

You can check the defualt water mark in `DefaultChannelConfig` -> `WriteBufferWaterMark.DEFAULT`. When data in `ChannelOutboundBuffer` > high water mark the isWritable return false, < low water mark return true.

```
 /**
 * Returns {@code true} if and only if the I/O thread will perform the
 * requested write operation immediately.  Any write requests made when
 * this method returns {@code false} are queued until the I/O thread is
 * ready to process the queued write requests.
 */
boolean isWritable();
```

Comment: @louxiu- if the data is being kept in out bound buffer even with writeandflush() function shouldnt number of bytes before unwritable decrease?

Comment: yes, it should decrease. How quick your server writes? bytesBeforeUnwritable will decrease when client os's receive buffer full and server os's send buffer full. Maybe you should block your client completely.

Comment: i checked after running a test-case by completely blocking the receive in the server. netty is basically used as a proxy between the client and server. The client kept sending a message in a loop and the message was also printed out to System.out along with a counter. The client eventually stops sending any more messages. The proxy keeps forwarding these messages and "never" becomes unwritable, nor does the bytebeforeunwritable decrease.

Comment: I suspect that what you are saying is true only if you are writing and not writing and flushing? as my understanding is simple "write" only writes to the channel buffer and not necessarily to the os buffer.? I have updated the code to show the printouts which I used for the test.

Comment: Write a sample code on gist. https://gist.github.com/louxiu/675027ae7563403dd8c71e4ae8ec095d

Comment: @louxiue - I have added some sample code to re-create the scenario that I have mentioned? Can you have a look at the source code, and let me know why my proxy would block? The only possible understanding is that in someway my configuration is different, but I have just picked the normal HexDump Proxy example provided in  netty.

Comment: thanks for the explanation...so the operation complete of writeAndFlush is blocking() and which is why future read() is not getting called. I have two follow up then: 1. Is there a way to separate out write and flush operations, such that future reads can be called without blocking, and the channel becomes not writable so that I can trigger an error in that case? 2. I understand channel.write() is not blocking, is channel.flush() operation blocking?

Comment: No.. writeAndFlush is not blocking. write and flush are all non-blocking. writeAndFlush will return immediately but the listener only be notified after the data is write to OS's buffer. 1. You can just move the channel.read out from the listener. I think it will trigger that case(producer is fast and consumer is slow) 2. flush is non-blocking. The example proxy is designed that way(quite simple and elegent), it is actually try to avoid the case you want to trigger.